# How can i subscribe/unsubscribe to a simplenews newsletter programmatically?

Tags: entities, database, hooks

I have the following code to set subscriptions to a simplenews newsletter on or off:

```
    $user_load = User::load($userID_current);
    $newsletter_subscriptions = [
        'newsletter1' => 'on',
        'newsletter2' => 'off',
        'newsletter3' => 'off',
        'newsletter4' => 'off',
    ];

    foreach ($newsletter_subscriptions as $system_name => $value) {

        $subscription_manager = \Drupal::service('simplenews.subscription_manager');

        $newsletter = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('simplenews_newsletter')
            ->loadByProperties(['system_name' => $system_name]);

        if ($value == 'on') {
            $subscription_manager->subscribe($user_load, $newsletter);
        } else {
            $subscription_manager->unsubscribe($user_load, $newsletter);
        }
    }
```

in the `$newsletter` i got back NULL even though the properties exists (checked by this:

```
$newsletter_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('simplenews_newsletter');
$system_names = $newsletter_storage->getQuery()
    ->execute();
foreach ($system_names as $system_name) {
    \Drupal::logger('simplenews')->info('Simplenews system name: @system_name', ['@system_name' => $system_name]);
}
```

whats wrong with my `$newsletter`? Does someone have experiences with simplenews 3?

Comment: This code does not prove at all that the property `system_name` exists. The array values resulting from `$query->execute()` are always [arrays of entity IDs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21Null%21Query.php/function/Query%3A%3Aexecute).

Answer (score -2):

It seems that chatGPT and Drupal are not best friends, so i had to find the solution the oldschool (long & painful) way. The solution was to provide the right subscribe() arguments, so i didn't need the $newsletter.

```
$user_load = User::load($userID_current);
$newsletter_subscriptions = [
    'newsletter1' => 'on',
    'newsletter2' => 'off',
    'newsletter3' => 'off',
    'newsletter4' => 'off',
];

foreach ($newsletter_subscriptions as $system_name => $value) {

    $subscription_manager = \Drupal::service('simplenews.subscription_manager');

    if ($value == 'on') {
        $subscription_manager->subscribe($user_load->getEmail(), $system_name);
    } else {
        $subscription_manager->unsubscribe($user_load->getEmail(), $system_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to put the line initializing `$subscription_manager` inside `foreach()`. It is sufficient to initialize the variable once.